# Работа с анонимными классами

Tags: php

Задался таким вот вопросом. Попробую описать.

Сначала примерный код:

```
class mysql {

    function __construct($db_config) {

        // Проверка $db_config и connect к базе

    }

    private function connect() {

        // Подключение к базе

    }

    public function query() {

        // запрос к базе, после всех необходимых сравнений у нас имеется переменная $this->query_id где либо false в случае неудачи или PDOStatement объект для дальнейшей работы

        return $this->query_id;

    }

}

$db = new mysql($db_config);

$db->query("select ....");
```

Хотелось бы чтобы функция query возвращала новый класс в котором будут дополнительные функции, например: $db->query('...')->fetch();

Собственно в чем загвоздка. Хотелось бы чтобы по запросу $db->query('...') отдавалась переменная $this->query_id. Так если возвращать объект, имеется только данные по объекту.

Такое вообще возможно в реализации?

Таким вот $db->query('...') образом мне хотелось бы получать и объект PDO, а в дальнейшем уже работать с ним за пределами класса, но чтобы когда обращаюсь например: $db->query('...')->fetch(); и когда $db->query('...') отдает false (то есть переменная $this->query_id) чтобы ->fetch() естественно тоже отдавал false. То есть в другом классе подключенном выше классе я мог бы прочитать $this->query_id и отдать false или ассоциативный массив.

Заморочился чет =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь, анонимные классы тут не при чем.

Если хочется расширить функциональность PDOStatement, то надо писать свой класс, вполне себе именованный, который дублирует его функциональность и добавляет эту непонятно зачем нужную переменную

```
class myStatement($stmt, $query_id)
{
    public function __construct($stmt, $query_id)
    {
        $this->query_id = $query_id;
        $this->stmt = $stmt;
    }
    public function fetch($params)
    {
        return $stmt->fetch(...$params);
    }
}
```

и отдаваь уже его

```
public function query() {

    // запрос к базе

    return new myStatement($stmt, $this->query_id);

}
```

соответственно, если хотим получить эту странную перменную, то

```
$db->query('...')->query_id;
```

если фетч, то

```
$db->query('...')->fetch();
```

если все вместе, то

```
$mystmt = $db->query('...');
$mystmt->query_id; 
$mystmt->fetch();
```